# Dynamically linking a date

Tags: ms-project

Here is my question: I have a go/no-go meeting on the calendar for go-live.  We always do go lives on Tuesday.  I want to dynamically link the date to always pick the next Tuesday after the go-live.  Is that possible?

I can see how to do it manually with a constraint, but if the go/no-go meeting moves up a week or back a week I have to go back in and make changes

Comment: I don't use Project a lot, but won't a one week finish-to-start constraint from go-live do it for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend this:

1. Create a custom calendar that only has Tuesdays as working days
2. Create a 1 day task in the schedule called "Go Live Start" or something and set it's Task Calendar to the calendar you created. Make it's predecessor the Go/No Go Meeting. **Do not load resource assignments onto this task**, it's strictly being created to achieve the mechanics of what you want to happen in the schedule. I would say just make this a milestone but milestones don't honor the task calendar set so you have to give it some duration.
3. Tie your actual discrete Go Live tasks Start-To-Start with the "Go Live Start" task.

Now no matter where your Go/No Go Meeting is moved to, your Go Live work will always begin on the following Tuesday.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Kenny.  That worked like a dream!

Comment: One other recommendation, give the "Go Live Start" task some successor like the program end or something so if the schedule is audited the auditors won't make a stink about tasks missing successors.